# Various printer deployment issue with Server 2012 R2

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, drivers, print-server, shared-printers

I have just set up a new remote desktop infrastructure, with all servers being built on Server 2012 R2. I have 7 session hosts, and a central file/print server.

On the print server, I have added network printers using their IP address, shared them, and listed in the directory. For each printer "Everyone" has print permissions, but not manage.
[image: Printers on print server]

I have then created a group policy object within which I have created printer entries with item-level targeting (to control who gets what printer).
[image: Deployed printers in group policy]

[image]

[image: Item level targeting]

The printers deploy ok, as I have also disabled point and print restrictions in the same group policy:
[image: Point and print settings]

The various issues we have:

- <strike>Some users of the HP printers, get duplicate printers deployed. They are the same printer, but one shows "on FLX-FS-V001", and the other shows "on 10.0.0.100"</strike>
- When printing PDFs, users occasionally get messages saying the document could not be print as no pages were selected. As far as I am aware, other applications are ok at this time
- Some users find their default printer is spontaneously changed to something like the OneNote 2013 printer, and when trying to change it back, they get a driver error

In most, if not all of these cases, doing a gpupdate /force, or restarting the print spooler seems to do the trick and kick things back into action. I have not currently found any events to indicate what may be causing this.

I have ensured I am using the latest x64 drivers for server 2012 R2 from the manufacturers website, but still a problem.

Does anyone have any past experience with this kind of issue, and able to advise what else I can try?

EDIT: Looks like I managed to get rid of the duplicated printers by setting a blank printer in the policy at the top of the list, and set it to remove all shared printers. Upon a log off/logon, only 1 instance of the printer was deployed.